# Modifying captured tokens from a regular expression?

Tags: regex, textmate

Using a general regular expression replacement (for me, I'm doing this through TextMate) is it possible to modify a captured token?

I've essentially got a handful of enums that I want to modify...

```
CONSTANT get { return 1; }
CONSTANT get { return 2; }
CONSTANT get { return 3; }
```

What I'd like to do is capture the "return x"...

```
return [\d]
```

... but then modify the return value by decrementing by 1

```
$1-1
```

Is there anyway to do this purely using regexps?

TIA!

Bob

Comment: Regexps by themselves don't give you editing superpowers; we need to know a bit about the environment. Which language is all this happening in? Is "TextMate" a program with a macro language? Please add an appropriate tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done purely using regexes. Arithmetics isn't a capability of regex. You need to write a script.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I figured I'd ask just to be certain.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that replaces 9 with 8, 8 with 7, 7 with 6, etc.